# Adding Controls To A Form Based On Number Of Listbox Items

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, listbox, controls

I figured out how to add a control to my form based on the number of items added to a listbox.

```
    ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text)
    TextBox1.Text = ""

    For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1

        'adds picturebox for as many listbox items added
        Dim MyPictureBox As New PictureBox()
        MyPictureBox.Location = New Point(25, 25)
        MyPictureBox.Size = New Size(15, 15)
        MyPictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
        Me.Controls.Add(MyPictureBox)
        MyPictureBox.Image = My.Resources.PDF_Info

    Next i
```

What I can't seem to figure out is how to add a second control, but add it in another location on the form.

So the first entry would place the picturebox at 25, 25 and when I enter a second item, it'll create another picturebox at 45, 45 and etc.

Can this be done?

Comment: you add + 20 if you want the control to be positioned at point  45,45 in the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text)
TextBox1.Text = ""
Dim x As Integer = 25
For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1

    'adds picturebox for as many listbox items added
    Dim MyPictureBox As New PictureBox()
    MyPictureBox.Location = New Point(x, x)
    MyPictureBox.Size = New Size(15, 15)
    MyPictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
    Me.Controls.Add(MyPictureBox)
    MyPictureBox.Image = My.Resources.PDF_Info
    x += 25
Next i
```

Comment: Thanks alot...appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

it will be something like this

```
ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text)
TextBox1.Text = ""
Dim p as Integer = 25

For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
    'adds picturebox for as many listbox items added
    Dim MyPictureBox As New PictureBox()
    MyPictureBox.Location = New Point(p , p)
    MyPictureBox.Size = New Size(15, 15)
    MyPictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
    Me.Controls.Add(MyPictureBox)
    MyPictureBox.Image = My.Resources.PDF_Info
   'add 20  to the current position of the control
   p = p + 20

Next i
```